# intellij doesn't have the VCS menu entry

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

I installed intellij on windows10. But the VCS menu item is missing. How can I make intellij display this menu item ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose the SVN menu.  Then select enable SVN repository and select the appropriate repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Preferences menu below. I'm on a Mac but it shouldn't matter. I had this enabled by default. Also, on the screenshot you can see the Restore actions (curved arrow icon) which are greyed out in my case because I haven't modified the Toolbar. If for some reason you don't have the VCS enabled by default (even if you are able to "Restore the defaults") you can compose your own, these settings are quite flexible.
[image]

Comment: it does not change, I have the exact same as you have, still no VCS  appeared on upper menu

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to press the button "Trust project" after opening any file.